# CSS layers and z-indexn

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, stylesheet

I apologize if my question is lacking information in which precisely helps you identify the issue I am having. I am having a browser war inside my own studio. If you could kindly navigate to this page: http://successbusinesssolutions.com/thespiritofsuccess you will see that in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Internet explorer that some of them display perfectly but in IE the Left Claim Bonus is cutoff.

For the life of me I cannot figure out what is going on. I've adjusted the z-index, played with the margins, etc. Anyone, if you can identify the problem I am not asking you to paste the source code over that is correct, but if you can point me in the right direction of what elemental conflict is causing my problem - that would be amazingly appreciated.

```
        <html><head>
          <title>
           Success Business Solutions
          </title>
          <style type="text/css">
           @font-face {
            font-family: copper;
            src: url('./f/Copperplate_Gothic_Bold_Condensed.ttf');
           }
           body {
             font-family:copper;
             background:#3b78bb;
             margin:0px;
             font-size:20px;
           }
           #blackbar {
              height:25px;
              background:#000;
              position:relative;
              top:0;
              width:100%;
              z-index:101;
           }
           #content {
              z-index:100;
              margin-left:auto;
              margin-right:auto;
              height:100%;
              overflow-y:hidden;    
              width:950px;
              background:#fff; 
           }

                    #popup1 { 
                        display:none; /* Hide the DIV */
                        position:relative;  
                        _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6 */  
                        height:300px;  
                        width:600px;  
                        background:#FFFFFF;  
                        top: 150px;
                        z-index:100; /* Layering ( on-top of others), if you have lots of layers: I just maximized, you can change it yourself */
                        margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;  

                        /* additional features, can be omitted */
                        border:10px solid #000;      
                        padding:15px;  
                        font-size:15px;  
                        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
                        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
                        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;

                     }

                     /* This is for the positioning of the Close Link */
                     #popupBox1Close {
                        font-size:20px;  
                        line-height:15px;  
                        right:5px;  
                        top:5px;  
                        position:absolute;  
                        color:#222;  
                        font-weight:500;      
                     }

                    #popup2 { 
                        display:none; /* Hide the DIV */
                        position:relative;  
                        _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6 */  
                        height:800px;  
                        width:700px;  
                        background:#fff;  
                        top: 20px;
                        z-index:100; /* Layering ( on-top of others), if you have lots of layers: I just maximized, you can change it yourself */
                        margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;

                        /* additional features, can be omitted */
                        border:10px solid #000;      
                        padding:15px;  
                        font-size:15px;  
                        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
                        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
                        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;

                     }

                     /* This is for the positioning of the Close Link */
                     #popupBox2Close {
                        font-size:20px;  
                        line-height:15px;  
                        right:5px;  
                        top:5px;  
                        position:absolute;  
                        color:#222;  
                        font-weight:500;      
                     }

          </style>
               <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>  
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready( function() {

                        // When site loaded, load the Popupbox First
                        loadPopupBox1();

                        $('#popupBox1Close').click( function() {            
                            unloadPopupBox1();
                        });


                        function unloadPopupBox1() {    // TO Unload the Popupbox
                            $('#popup1').fadeOut("slow");
                            $("#container").css({ // this is just for style        
                                "opacity": "1"  
                            }); 
                        }    

                        function loadPopupBox1() {    // To Load the Popupbox
                            $( "#my-button-1" ).click(function() {
                                  $('#popup1').fadeIn("slow");

                                    $("#container").css({ // this is just for style
                                        "opacity": ".01"
                                    });
                             });         
                        }      

                        // When site loaded, load the Popupbox First
                        loadPopupBox2();

                        $('#popupBox2Close').click( function() {            
                            unloadPopupBox2();
                        });


                        function unloadPopupBox2() {    // TO Unload the Popupbox
                            $('#popup2').fadeOut("slow");
                            $("#container").css({ // this is just for style        
                                "opacity": "1"  
                            }); 
                        }    

                        function loadPopupBox2() {    // To Load the Popupbox
                            $( "#my-button-2" ).click(function() {
                                  $('#popup2').fadeIn("slow");

                                    $("#container").css({ // this is just for style
                                        "opacity": ".01"
                                    });
                             });         
                        }   



                    });
                </script>   

         </head>
         <body style="">
         <div id="popup1">
                <center><h2>Put in your name and email to claim gift 1</h2></center>
                <br><br><script type="text/javascript" src="http://forms.aweber.com/form/87/1604373587.js"></script><style type="text/css">#af-form-1604373587 .af-body .af-textWrap{width:98%;display:block;float:none;}#af-form-1604373587 .af-body input.text, #af-form-1604373587 .af-body textarea{background-color:#FFFFFF;border-color:#919191;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;}#af-form-1604373587 .af-body input.text:focus, #af-form-1604373587 .af-body textarea:focus{background-color:#FFFAD6;border-color:#030303;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;}#af-form-1604373587 .af-body label.previewLabel{display:block;float:none;text-align:left;width:auto;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;}#af-form-1604373587 .af-body{padding-bottom:15px;padding-top:15px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:inherit;background-image:none;color:#000000;font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;}#af-form-1604373587 .af-quirksMode{padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;}#af-form-1604373587 .af-standards .af-element{padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;}#af-form-1604373587 .buttonContainer input.submit{background-image:url("http://forms.aweber.com/images/auto/gradient/button/07c.png");background-position:top left;background-repeat:repeat-x;background-color:#0057ac;border:1px solid #0057ac;color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;}#af-form-1604373587 .buttonContainer input.submit{width:auto;}#af-form-1604373587 .buttonContainer{text-align:right;}#af-form-1604373587 button,#af-form-1604373587 input,#af-form-1604373587 submit,#af-form-1604373587 textarea,#af-form-1604373587 select,#af-form-1604373587 label,#af-form-1604373587 optgroup,#af-form-1604373587 option{float:none;position:static;margin:0;}#af-form-1604373587 div{margin:0;}#af-form-1604373587 form,#af-form-1604373587 textarea,.af-form-wrapper,.af-form-close-button,#af-form-1604373587 img{float:none;color:inherit;position:static;background-color:none;border:none;margin:0;padding:0;}#af-form-1604373587 input,#af-form-1604373587 button,#af-form-1604373587 textarea,#af-form-1604373587 select{font-size:100%;}#af-form-1604373587 select,#af-form-1604373587 label,#af-form-1604373587 optgroup,#af-form-1604373587 option{padding:0;}#af-form-1604373587,#af-form-1604373587 .quirksMode{width:240px;}#af-form-1604373587.af-quirksMode{overflow-x:hidden;}#af-form-1604373587{background-color:#FFFFFF;border-color:#FFFFFF;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;}#af-form-1604373587{display:block;}#af-form-1604373587{overflow:hidden;}.af-body .af-textWrap{text-align:left;}.af-body input.image{border:none!important;}.af-body input.submit,.af-body input.image,.af-form .af-element input.button{float:none!important;}.af-body input.text{width:100%;float:none;padding:2px!important;}.af-body.af-standards input.submit{padding:4px 12px;}.af-clear{clear:both;}.af-element label{text-align:left;display:block;float:left;}.af-element{padding:5px 0;}.af-form-wrapper{text-indent:0;}.af-form{text-align:left;margin:auto;}.af-quirksMode .af-element{padding-left:0!important;padding-right:0!important;}.lbl-right .af-element label{text-align:right;}body {}</style><form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"><div style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="1604373587"><input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value=""><input type="hidden" name="listname" value="sbsoption1"><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://successbusinesssolutions.com/thespiritofsuccess/thankyou.php" id="redirect_c86c0435ee35964047b160ef6b2e75c2"><input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="SBS_Option_Gift_1"><input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="name,email"><input type="hidden" name="meta_forward_vars" value="1"><input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value=""></div><div id="af-form-1604373587" class="af-form"><div id="af-body-1604373587" class="af-body af-standards"><div class="af-element"><label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-54897735">Name: </label><div class="af-textWrap"><input id="awf_field-54897735" type="text" name="name" class="text" value="" tabindex="500"></div><div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element"><label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-54897736">Email: </label><div class="af-textWrap"><input class="text" id="awf_field-54897736" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="501"></div><div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element buttonContainer"><input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="502"><div class="af-clear"></div></div></div></div></form><script type="text/javascript">    <!--    (function() {        var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;        if (!IE) { return; }        if (document.compatMode && document.compatMode == 'BackCompat') {            if (document.getElementById("af-form-1604373587")) {                document.getElementById("af-form-1604373587").className = 'af-form af-quirksMode';            }            if (document.getElementById("af-body-1604373587")) {                document.getElementById("af-body-1604373587").className = "af-body inline af-quirksMode";            }            if (document.getElementById("af-header-1604373587")) {                document.getElementById("af-header-1604373587").className = "af-header af-quirksMode";            }            if (document.getElementById("af-footer-1604373587")) {                document.getElementById("af-footer-1604373587").className = "af-footer af-quirksMode";            }        }    })();    --></script>
                <center><a id="popupBox1Close" href="#">[X]</a></center> 

         </div>
         <div id="popup2">
                <center><h2>Please fill out this survey for your 30 minute consultation!</h2></center>
               <!-- AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0 -->
        <style type="text/css">
        #af-form-1181199911 .af-body .af-textWrap, #af-form-1181199911 .af-body .af-selectWrap, #af-form-1181199911 .af-body .af-checkWrap, #af-form-1181199911 .choiceList-radio-inline, #af-form-1181199911 .choiceList-radio-stacked{width:98%;display:block;float:none;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .af-body a{color:#094C80;text-decoration:underline;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .af-body input.text, #af-form-1181199911 .af-body textarea{background-color:#FFFFFF;border-color:#919191;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .af-body input.text:focus, #af-form-1181199911 .af-body textarea:focus{background-color:#FFFAD6;border-color:#030303;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .af-body label.choice{color:inherit;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:inherit;font-family:inherit;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .af-body label.previewLabel{display:block;float:none;text-align:left;width:auto;color:#000000;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .af-body{padding-bottom:15px;padding-top:15px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:inherit;background-image:none;color:#000000;font-size:11px;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .af-element-radio{margin-left:10px;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .af-quirksMode .bodyText{padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:2px;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .af-quirksMode{padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .af-standards .af-element{padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .bodyText p{margin:1em 0;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .buttonContainer input.submit{background-image:url("http://forms.aweber.com/images/auto/gradient/button/07c.png");background-position:top left;background-repeat:repeat-x;background-color:#0057ac;border:1px solid #0057ac;color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:14px;font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .buttonContainer input.submit{width:auto;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .buttonContainer{text-align:right;}
        #af-form-1181199911 .choiceList-radio-inline .af-element-radio{margin-right:0px;}
        #af-form-1181199911 body,#af-form-1181199911 dl,#af-form-1181199911 dt,#af-form-1181199911 dd,#af-form-1181199911 h1,#af-form-1181199911 h2,#af-form-1181199911 h3,#af-form-1181199911 h4,#af-form-1181199911 h5,#af-form-1181199911 h6,#af-form-1181199911 pre,#af-form-1181199911 code,#af-form-1181199911 fieldset,#af-form-1181199911 legend,#af-form-1181199911 blockquote,#af-form-1181199911 th,#af-form-1181199911 td{float:none;color:inherit;position:static;margin:0;padding:0;}
        #af-form-1181199911 button,#af-form-1181199911 input,#af-form-1181199911 submit,#af-form-1181199911 textarea,#af-form-1181199911 select,#af-form-1181199911 label,#af-form-1181199911 optgroup,#af-form-1181199911 option{float:none;position:static;margin:0;}
        #af-form-1181199911 div{margin:0;}
        #af-form-1181199911 fieldset{border:0;}
        #af-form-1181199911 form,#af-form-1181199911 textarea,.af-form-wrapper,.af-form-close-button,#af-form-1181199911 img{float:none;color:inherit;position:static;background-color:none;border:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
        #af-form-1181199911 input,#af-form-1181199911 button,#af-form-1181199911 textarea,#af-form-1181199911 select{font-size:100%;}
        #af-form-1181199911 p{color:inherit;}
        #af-form-1181199911 select,#af-form-1181199911 label,#af-form-1181199911 optgroup,#af-form-1181199911 option{padding:0;}
        #af-form-1181199911 table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
        #af-form-1181199911 ul,#af-form-1181199911 ol{list-style-image:none;list-style-position:outside;list-style-type:disc;padding-left:40px;}
        #af-form-1181199911,#af-form-1181199911 .quirksMode{width:590px;}
        #af-form-1181199911.af-quirksMode{overflow-x:hidden;}
        #af-form-1181199911{background-color:#F0F0F0;border-color:#CFCFCF;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;}
        #af-form-1181199911{display:block;}
        #af-form-1181199911{overflow:hidden;}
        .af-body .af-textWrap{text-align:left;}
        .af-body input.image{border:none!important;}
        .af-body input.submit,.af-body input.image,.af-form .af-element input.button{float:none!important;}
        .af-body input.text{width:100%;float:none;padding:2px!important;}
        .af-body.af-standards input.submit{padding:4px 12px;}
        .af-clear{clear:both;}
        .af-element input.radio{width:inherit!important;}
        .af-element label{text-align:left;display:block;float:left;}
        .af-element-checkbox .choice,.af-element-radio label{display:inline;}
        .af-element-checkbox label,.af-element-checkbox input.checkbox,.af-element-radio label,.af-element-radio input.radio{display:inline!important;float:none!important;}
        .af-element-radio.inline{float:left;margin-left:0;margin-right:7px;}
        .af-element.radio{display:block!important;}
        .af-element{padding:5px 0;}
        .af-form-wrapper{text-indent:0;}
        .af-form{text-align:left;margin:auto;}
        .af-quirksMode .af-element{padding-left:0!important;padding-right:0!important;}
        .choiceList-radio-inline .af-element-radio{float:left;}
        .lbl-right .af-element label{text-align:right;}
        body {
        }
        </style>
        <form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl">
        <div style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="1181199911">
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="listname" value="sbsoption2">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://successbusinesssolutions.com/thespiritofsuccess/surveythankyou.php" id="redirect_16ba09f5d2d8a37223abb86e4a231529">

        <input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="sbsoption2">
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1001">
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="name,email,custom Phone,custom Are you a new business owner or do you have experience running a business before,custom Are you buying a franchise or starting your own business,custom Are you operating the business on your own or with a partner,custom How much start up capital do you have">
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_forward_vars" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="">
        </div>
        <div id="af-form-1181199911" class="af-form"><div id="af-body-1181199911" class="af-body af-standards">
        <div class="af-element">
        <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-55421303">Name: </label>
        <div class="af-textWrap">
        <input id="awf_field-55421303" type="text" name="name" class="text" value="" tabindex="500">
        </div>
        <div class="af-clear"></div></div>
        <div class="af-element">
        <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-55421304">Email: </label>
        <div class="af-textWrap"><input class="text" id="awf_field-55421304" type="text" name="email" value="" tabindex="501">
        </div><div class="af-clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="af-element">
        <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-55421305">Phone: (please include country and area code)</label>
        <div class="af-textWrap"><input type="text" id="awf_field-55421305" class="text" name="custom Phone" value="" tabindex="502"></div>
        <div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element"><div><label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-554213060">Are you a new business owner or do you have experience running a business before:</label><div class="choiceList choiceList-radio-stacked">
        <div class="af-element-radio multiChoice">
        <input class="radio" type="radio" id="awf_field-554213060" name="custom Are you a new business owner or do you have experience running a business before" value="New to Business" tabindex="503"> 
        <label class="choice" for="awf_field-554213060">New to Business</label>
        <div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element-radio multiChoice">
        <input class="radio" type="radio" id="awf_field-554213061" name="custom Are you a new business owner or do you have experience running a business before" value="Some Experience" tabindex="504"> 
        <label class="choice" for="awf_field-554213061">Some Experience</label>
        <div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element-radio multiChoice">
        <input class="radio" type="radio" id="awf_field-554213062" name="custom Are you a new business owner or do you have experience running a business before" value="Many years of Experience" tabindex="505"> 
        <label class="choice" for="awf_field-554213062">Many years of Experience</label>
        <div class="af-clear"></div></div></div></div><div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element"><div><label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-554213070">Are you buying a franchise or starting your own business:</label><div class="choiceList choiceList-radio-stacked">
        <div class="af-element-radio multiChoice">
        <input class="radio" type="radio" id="awf_field-554213070" name="custom Are you buying a franchise or starting your own business" value="Yes! I am buying a Franchise." tabindex="506"> 
        <label class="choice" for="awf_field-554213070">Yes! I am buying a Franchise.</label>
        <div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element-radio multiChoice">
        <input class="radio" type="radio" id="awf_field-554213071" name="custom Are you buying a franchise or starting your own business" value="Yes! I am starting my own Business" tabindex="507"> 
        <label class="choice" for="awf_field-554213071">Yes! I am starting my own Business</label>
        <div class="af-clear"></div></div></div></div><div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element"><div><label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-554213130">Are you operating the business on your own or with a partner:</label><div class="choiceList choiceList-radio-stacked">
        <div class="af-element-radio multiChoice">
        <input class="radio" type="radio" id="awf_field-554213130" name="custom Are you operating the business on your own or with a partner" value="By Myself" tabindex="508"> 
        <label class="choice" for="awf_field-554213130">By Myself</label>
        <div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element-radio multiChoice">
        <input class="radio" type="radio" id="awf_field-554213131" name="custom Are you operating the business on your own or with a partner" value="With a Partner" tabindex="509"> 
        <label class="choice" for="awf_field-554213131">With a Partner</label>
        <div class="af-clear"></div></div></div></div><div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element">
        <div class="bodyText"><p><span style="font-size: 16px;"><span style="font-family: Verdana;">Do you need help with:</span>&nbsp;</span></p></div><div class="af-clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="af-element af-element-checkbox"><div class="af-checkWrap">
        <input type="checkbox" value="yes" id="awf_field-55421308" class="checkbox" name="custom Systems" tabindex="510"> 
        <label class="choice" for="awf_field-55421308">Systems</label>
        </div><div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element af-element-checkbox"><div class="af-checkWrap">
        <input type="checkbox" value="yes" id="awf_field-55421309" class="checkbox" name="custom Marketing" tabindex="511"> 
        <label class="choice" for="awf_field-55421309">Marketing</label>
        </div><div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element af-element-checkbox"><div class="af-checkWrap">
        <input type="checkbox" value="yes" id="awf_field-55421310" class="checkbox" name="custom Staff Management" tabindex="512"> 
        <label class="choice" for="awf_field-55421310">Staff Management</label>
        </div><div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element af-element-checkbox"><div class="af-checkWrap">
        <input type="checkbox" value="yes" id="awf_field-55421311" class="checkbox" name="custom Cash Flow" tabindex="513"> 
        <label class="choice" for="awf_field-55421311">Cash Flow</label>
        </div><div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element af-element-checkbox"><div class="af-checkWrap">
        <input type="checkbox" value="yes" id="awf_field-55421312" class="checkbox" name="custom All of the Above" tabindex="514"> 
        <label class="choice" for="awf_field-55421312">All of the Above</label>
        </div><div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element">
        <label class="previewLabel" for="awf_field-55421314">How much start up capital do you have:</label>
        <div class="af-selectWrap"><select id="awf_field-55421314" name="custom How much start up capital do you have" tabindex="515"> 
        <option class="multiChoice" value="None">None</option>
        <option class="multiChoice" value="2000-5000">2000-5000</option>
        <option class="multiChoice" value="5000-10000">5000-10000</option>
        <option class="multiChoice" value="10000+">10000+</option>
        </select>
        </div><input type="hidden" name="meta_preselected_awf_field-55421314" value=""><div class="af-clear"></div></div><div class="af-element buttonContainer">
        <input name="submit" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" tabindex="516">
        <div class="af-clear"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none;"></div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            (function() {
                var IE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
                if (!IE) { return; }
                if (document.compatMode && document.compatMode == 'BackCompat') {
                    if (document.getElementById("af-form-1181199911")) {
                        document.getElementById("af-form-1181199911").className = 'af-form af-quirksMode';
                    }
                    if (document.getElementById("af-body-1181199911")) {
                        document.getElementById("af-body-1181199911").className = "af-body inline af-quirksMode";
                    }
                    if (document.getElementById("af-header-1181199911")) {
                        document.getElementById("af-header-1181199911").className = "af-header af-quirksMode";
                    }
                    if (document.getElementById("af-footer-1181199911")) {
                        document.getElementById("af-footer-1181199911").className = "af-footer af-quirksMode";
                    }
                }
            })();
            -->
        </script>

        <!-- /AWeber Web Form Generator 3.0 -->        <center><a id="popupBox2Close" href="#">[X]</a></center> 

         </div>
         <center>
           <div id="container">
           <div id="blackbar"></div>
           <div id="content">
            <img src="./i/sbs_logo.gif">
                <img src="./i/thanks.gif" style="">
                <div id="mathieson" style="margin-top:0px;margin-left:20px;">
                  <br><img src="./i/mathieson.gif"><br>
              <div style="font-size:16px;width:350px;text-align:center;">Leigh and Teriann Matheson<br>Ceo's &amp; Founders of Success Business Solutions</div>
                </div>
                <div id="bonus" style="float:right;width:497px;position:relative;margin-top: -382px;">
                   <h1 style="margin-left:20px;">Complimentary Bonuses!</h1>
                   <table width="70%" align="center" style="margin-left: -34px;float: left;width: 497px;">
                <tbody><tr>
                      <td valign="top" width="50%" align="center">
                              <span style="color:#3b78bb;font-size:20px;">The Top 7 Solutions To New Business Challenges</span><br>
                              <br>
                              Solve common business owner challenges with strategic success solutions to maximize results.
                      <br><br>
                    <ul style="margin-bottom:-15px;text-align:left;">
                     <li>Set up business success systems</li>
                     <li>Maximize cash flow</li>
                         <li>Increase Revenue</li>
                    </ul>
                      <br>
                              <center><img id="my-button-1" src="./i/claim_bonus.gif"><br>($97 Value)</center>
                          </td>
                          <td valign="top" width="50%" align="center">
                              <span style="color:#3b78bb;font-size:20px;">30 Minute Business Success Strategy </span><br>
                              <br>
                      Take your business to the next level and increase revenue by solving your top 3 business owner challenges with Success Business Solutions
                              <br> 
                              <ul style="margin-bottom:-15px;text-align:left;">
                    <li>Solve common Challenges every business owner faces</li>
                    <li>Set Up a Success Business Blueprint</li> 
                        <li>Maximize Results</li>
                              </ul>
                              <center><img id="my-button-2" src="./i/claim_bonus.gif"><br>($197 Value)</center>
                          </td>
                </tr>
               </tbody></table>
                </div>
           </div>
           </div>
           </center> 


        <script id="hiddenlpsubmitdiv" style="display: none;"></script>   <script>try{for(var lastpass_iter=0; lastpass_iter < document.forms.length; lastpass_iter++){ var lastpass_f = document.forms[lastpass_iter]; if(typeof(lastpass_f.lpsubmitorig2)=="undefined"){ lastpass_f.lpsubmitorig2 = lastpass_f.submit; lastpass_f.submit = function(){ var form=this; var customEvent = document.createEvent("Event"); customEvent.initEvent("lpCustomEvent", true, true); var d = document.getElementById("hiddenlpsubmitdiv"); if (d) {for(var i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++){ if(document.forms[i]==form){ d.innerText=i; } } d.dispatchEvent(customEvent); }form.lpsubmitorig2(); } } }}catch(e){}</script></body></html>
```

- Andrew

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: I will add the source here for you.

Comment: Please see "[Tricks for Trimming](http://sscce.org/#trim)" on SSCCE.org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was ultimately because I had limited a table to X pixels. Chrome, Safari, and Firefox let it slide and overflowed the content. Internet Explorer (9) did not let it overflow.

Thanks all that helped. :p